# Pattern using nested loop in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

Can anyone help me to print this pattern in python 3.x version:

```
A
A B
A B C
A B C D
A B C D E
```

write the code in such a way so as to be able to accept the number of lines from the user.
Kindly explain the steps of ur code.

Comment: SO is not a code factory. Show us what you have tried and tell us where you got stuck and we will help gladly

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(int(input('number: '))):
    print(' '.join(chr( ord('A') +  k % 26 ) for k in range(0, i + 1)))
```